# Python Assign value to variable during condition in while Loop

Tags: python, while-loop, variable-assignment

A simple question about Python syntax. I want to assign a value from a function to a variable during the condition for a while loop. When the value returned from the function is false, the loop should break. I know how to do it in PHP.

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($fh, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
```

However when I try a similar syntax in Python I get a syntax error.

Comment: If you had a function `fgetcsv` in Python that returned either a string or `False`, so exactly the same pattern as you have in PHP, then `for data in iter(lambda: fgetcsv(fh, 1000, ","), False):` would have the effect you desire.

Comment: @Duncan - Huh... what if you wanted a more generic `iter` that would consider any `False`y value as the sentinel?

Comment: I updated my answer for 2020; the := operator exists since Python 3.8.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You cannot use assignment in an expression. Assignment is itself a statement, and you cannot combine Python statements.

This is an explicit choice made by the language designers; it is all too easy to accidentally use one `=` and assign, where you meant to use two `==` and test for equality.

Move the assignment *into* the loop, or assign *before* the loop, and assign new values in the loop itself.

For your specific example, the Python [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) gives you a higher-level API and you'd be looping over the `csv.reader()` instead:

```
with open(csvfilename, 'rb') as csvfh:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfh)
    for row in reader:
```

I **rarely**, if ever, need to assign in a loop construct. Usually there is a (much) better way of solving the problem at hand.

That said, as of Python 3.8 the language will actually have assignment expressions, using `:=` as the assignment operator. See [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/). Assignment expressions are actually useful in list comprehensions, for example, when you need to both include a method return value in the list you are building and need to be able to use that value in a test.

Now, you'd have to use a generator expression:

```
absolute = (os.path.abspath(p) for p in files)
filtered = [abs for abs in absolute if included(abs)]
```

but with assignment expressions you can inline the `os.path.abspath()` call:

```
filtered = [abs for p in files if included(abs := os.path.abspath(p))]
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually need this for something else than csv , sorry if I was confusing.

Comment: @BorutFlis: Sure, but again, make sure you check for better ways of achieving this.

Comment: Just learning Python and love it for its conciseness. This is the first thing that upset me, even though I can understand the choice made by the language designers...

Comment: @opncow: actually, Python 3.8 will have an assignment expression.  See [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/).

Answer (score 48):

**2020 answer:**

Since Python 3.8, the ["walrus operator" :=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297704/syntax-and-assignment-expressions-what-and-why) exists that does exactly what you want:

```
while data := fgetcsv(fh, 1000, ",") != False:
    pass
```

(if that fgetcsv function existed)

**2013 answer:**
You can't do that in Python, no assignment in expressions. At least that means you won't accidentally type == instead of = or the other way around and have it work.

Traditional Python style is to just use while True and break:

```
while True:
    data = fgetcsv(fh, 1000, ",")
    if not data:
        break
    # Use data here
```

But nowadays I'd put that in a generator:

```
def data_parts(fh):
    while True:
        data = fgetcsv(fh, 1000, ",")
        if not data:
            break
        yield data
```

so that in the code that uses the file, the ugliness is hidden away:

```
for data in data_parts(fh):
    # Use data here
```

Of course if it's actually CSV reading that you're doing, use the csv module.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to use the infinitive loop.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Great example of a simple generator instead of while loop.

Answer (score 5):

Python 3.8 [pep-0572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#syntax-and-semantics) now address this case using the new notation `:=`. Have a look :)

For example:

```py
while chunk := file.read(8192):
   process(chunk)
```

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a little Python module, which I call [`let`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/let/1.0.0), which allows you to perform a variable assignment anywhere that a function is allowed.

Install it like this:

```
pip install let
```

I believe the following will accomplish what you're looking for:

```
from let import let

while let(data = fgetcsv(fh, 1000, ',')):
    # Do whatever you'd like with data here
```

However... Duncan's comment the original question saying to use `iter` is interesting. I wasn't aware of the function until he brought it up, and I now believe it may be a better solution than mine. It's debatable - `iter` requires a sentinel to be explicitly provided, whereas mine doesn't care and simply waits for `fgetcsv` to return any `False`y value.