# Can I assign the value of the left hand side of a Boolean expression (e.g in a while loop) to something?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean, conditional-statements, variable-assignment

Is there a syntax to capture a result evaluated in a Boolean expression? In other words, what was the result that caused the Boolean to be True?

A concrete example - I want the second largest number in a set, regardless of how often the largest number is duplicated:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
h = nums.pop()
while nums.pop() == h:
    pass
print(nums.pop())
```

Obviously returns 2, because the 3 has gone in evaluating the expression. Is there something like:

```
while (i = nums.pop()) == h:

#Do something with i
```

Comment: Strictly speaking; no, you cannot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767891/python-assign-value-to-variable-during-condition-in-while-loop

Comment: Good background, thanks.