# Is there a while(input()) loop in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a python solution to [How many digits](https://open.kattis.com/problems/howmanydigits) on Kattis which requires a while(input()) loop I have a C++ solution using

```cpp
int n;
while( cin >> n ) {}
```

but I was wondering if there was a way to do this in python 3.x

Comment: Only in Python 3.8: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297704/syntax-and-assignment-expressions-what-and-why

Comment: Are you getting data from a file or from standard input?

Comment: Of course, you can always make the condition `while True:` and then `break` if there's no more input.

Comment: I am taking a standard input not reading from a file

Answer (score 0):

I usually code it like this:

```py
try:
    while True:
        n = int(input())
        ...
except EOFError:
    pass
```

Once there is no more input to read, the `input()` call will throw an EOFError and exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop instead of a while
for  in 
where var is a variable and iterable is a list

Comment: When you'll get 50 reputation, remember to use comments for such tips.