# Understanding the reason for the new python := operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, language-design, python-3.8, python-assignment-expression

This is kind of a meta programming question: I'd like to understand why python developers introduced yet another operator with the new [`:=`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297704/syntax-and-assignment-expressions-what-and-why). I know what it's for. I would, however, like to know, why the developers chose a new symbol instead of re-using e.g. the `as` operator.

I.e. why was it deemed preferable to write

```
while (command := input("> ")) != "quit":
    print("You entered:", command)
```

rather than

```
while input("> ") as command != "quit":
    print("You entered:", command)
```

Comment: Well `as` is a keyword that is already part of the language, e.g. `import itertools as it` or `with open(file) as f:` etc.

Comment: Exactly my point. It already has two uses, like `from`. Why not add a third?

Comment: I presume that the parsing is easier for the new symbol than overloading the `as` operator (maybe ambiguities?). Also makes it easier for users to differentiate uses than having one symbol /operator for many different cases

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#alternative-spellings

Comment: @Chris_Rands Thank you, this basically answered it. I must have skipped that while reading the PEP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is answered in [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#alternative-spellings)

> ## Alternative spellings
>
> Broadly the same semantics as the current
>   proposal, but spelled differently.
>
> `EXPR as NAME`:
>
> `stuff = [[f(x) as y, x/y] for x in range(5)]`
>
> Since `EXPR as NAME` already has meaning in `import`, `except` and `with`
>   statements (with different semantics), this would create unnecessary
>   confusion or require special-casing (e.g. to forbid assignment within
>   the headers of these statements).
>
> (Note that `with EXPR as VAR` does not simply assign the value of `EXPR`
>   to `VAR` -- it calls `EXPR.__enter__()` and assigns the result of that to
>   `VAR`.)
>
> Additional reasons to prefer `:=` over this spelling include:
>
> In `if f(x) as y` the assignment target doesn't jump out at you -- it
>   just reads like `if f x blah blah` and it is too similar visually to `if
>   f(x) and y`.
>
> In all other situations where an `as` clause is allowed, even readers
>   with intermediary skills are led to anticipate that clause (however
>   optional) by the keyword that starts the line, and the grammar ties
>   that keyword closely to the `as` clause:
>
> ```
> import foo as bar
>
> except Exc as var
>
> with ctxmgr() as var
> ```
>
> To the contrary, the assignment expression does not belong to the `if` or `while`
>   that starts the line, and we intentionally allow assignment
>   expressions in other contexts as well.
>
> The parallel cadence between
>
> ```
> NAME = EXPR
>
> if NAME := EXPR
> ```
>
> reinforces the visual recognition of
>   assignment expressions.