# How to convert values in place in a python for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

In this simple python example:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
for n in arr: 
    s = str(n)
    print(s)
```

What I want to write is a code somehow similar `to [str(n) for n in arr]` but in the following format:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
for str(n) as s in arr: 
    print(s)
```

I basically want to include `s=str(s)` inside `for` statement. Is the any handy way to do so in python?

Comment: What result to you expect exactly ? The list comprehension is a way to store elements not print them. Just do `for n in arr:  print(n) ` no need to pass to `str`

Comment: The first example is fine, but you could just use `print(n)` directly. The second example with the list comprehension is also just fine. The third example doesn’t make sense, though.

Comment: Can you clarify what your goal is? Do you want to convert the list in place, convert the element in the for loop, or just print the values as strings?

Comment: Your desired format is very obviously a syntax error. Just to be clear: You want to *remove* the single line ``s = str(s)``, and still want `s` to be a ``str`` regardless of its initial type?

Comment: It seems you are looking for the "walrus operator". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297704/syntax-and-assignment-expressions-what-and-why

Comment: so it will be `for s:=str(s) in arr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two ways:

#### `map:`

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
for s in map(str, arr): 
    print(s)
```

#### generator comprehensions:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
for s in (str(n) for n in arr):
    print(s)
```

Comment: Which one is faster? 
it would be nice if they add such keyword to make it even nicer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `str` at all. The `print` function converts its arguments to strings automatically.

So you can simply use:

```
for n in arr:
    print(n)
```

no matter what `n` is.

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

Comment: It is not about the str() method. That is just an example. How can I make that operation inside for loop?