# Tried to use the walrus operator on a unsupported version of python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tqdm

so this works on my pc running v3.8.5 but on my pc with python v3.7.3 it throws a syntax error and points to '  :=  ' as the error.

```
ls = ['hi', 'hello', 'bye', 'goodbye', 'adios']

for i in (t := tqdm(ls, ncols=103, leave=False, ascii=' #')):
    t.set_description(i)
    sleep(1)
```

i know i can just do

```
t = tqdm(ls, ncols=103, leave=False, ascii=' #')

for i in t:
    t.set_description(i)
    sleep(1)
```

but would rather not... Any ideas what the issue is? both machines are running same version of tqdm.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? The issue is precisely that ``:=`` is a syntax error in Python 3.7 – it was added in Python 3.8. There is no further issue than what Python is telling you itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“:=” syntax and assignment expressions: what and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297704/syntax-and-assignment-expressions-what-and-why)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The walrus operator is a new addition in Python 3.8.  See PEP 572:

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/