# Polars Expressions Failed to Access Intermediate Column Creation Expressions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-polars

I want to encode the `non-zero` binary events with integer numbers. Following is a demo table:

```py
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "event": [0, 1, 1, 0],
        "foo": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "boo": [2, 3, 4, 5],
    }
)
```

The expected output is achieved by:

```py
df = df.with_row_index()
events = df.select(pl.col(["index", "event"])).filter(pl.col("event") == 1).with_row_index("event_id").drop("event")
df = df.join(events, on="index", how="left")

out:
shape: (4, 5)
┌───────┬───────┬─────┬─────┬──────────┐
│ index ┆ event ┆ foo ┆ boo ┆ event_id │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---      │
│ u32   ┆ i64   ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ u32      │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═════╪═════╪══════════╡
│ 0     ┆ 0     ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ null     │
│ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 0        │
│ 2     ┆ 1     ┆ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 1        │
│ 3     ┆ 0     ┆ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ null     │
└───────┴───────┴─────┴─────┴──────────┘
```

I want to get the expeceted output by **chaining the expressions**:

```py
(
    df
    .with_row_index()
    .join(
        df
        .select(pl.col(["index", "event"]))
        .filter(pl.col("event") == 1)
        .with_row_index("event_id")
        .drop("event"),
        on="index",
        how="left",
        )
    )
```

However, the expressions within the `.join()` expression does not seem to have added `index` column from the `df.with_row_index()` operation:

```py
ColumnNotFoundError: index

Error originated just after this operation:
DF ["event", "foo", "boo"]; PROJECT */3 COLUMNS; SELECTION: "None"
```

Comment: [`.pipe()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.pipe.html#polars.DataFrame.pipe) is how to chain such operations in Polars. (Although @Hericks answer is the way to go in this case.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the solution using the [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html) works. It is probably more idiomatic and cleaner to use a [`pl.when().then()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.when.html) construct in conjunction with [`pl.int_range()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.int_range.html) to create the `event_id`.

```py
(
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.when(pl.col("event") == 1)
        .then(pl.int_range(pl.len()))
        .over("event")
        .alias("event_id")
    )
)
```

```
shape: (4, 4)
┌───────┬─────┬─────┬──────────┐
│ event ┆ foo ┆ boo ┆ event_id │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---      │
│ i64   ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64      │
╞═══════╪═════╪═════╪══════════╡
│ 0     ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ null     │
│ 1     ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 0        │
│ 1     ┆ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 1        │
│ 0     ┆ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ null     │
└───────┴─────┴─────┴──────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use `:=` operator:

```py
df = (df := df.with_row_index()).join(
    df.select(pl.col(["index", "event"]))
    .filter(pl.col("event") == 1)
    .with_row_index("event_id")
    .drop("event"),
    on="index",
    how="left",
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
shape: (4, 5)
┌───────┬───────┬─────┬─────┬──────────┐
│ index ┆ event ┆ foo ┆ boo ┆ event_id │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---      │
│ u32   ┆ i64   ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ u32      │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═════╪═════╪══════════╡
│ 0     ┆ 0     ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ null     │
│ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 0        │
│ 2     ┆ 1     ┆ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 1        │
│ 3     ┆ 0     ┆ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ null     │
└───────┴───────┴─────┴─────┴──────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what does the `:=` operator do?

Comment: @KevinLi [Here is related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297704/what-are-assignment-expressions-using-the-walrus-or-operator-why-was-t) on StackOverflow. Basically it means assign the result from `df.with_row_index()` to `df` and return `df` (so you can chain your operations afterwards).